# Kafka Druid integration with Streaming Analytics Manager

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, druid, hortonworks-sam

I am trying to push data from Kafka to Druid using Streaming Analytics Manager(SAM), seems like the data are not even going to the Kafka source in SAM.

I am thinking that source might be not seted correctly in SAM. Any experience with this topic?

My confing for kafka source:

```
Cluser name: Sandbox
Bootstrap server: sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com:6667
Security protocol: PLAINTEXT
```

My confing for druid target:

```
name of the indexing service: druid/overlord
service discovery path: /druid/discovery
Zookeeper connect string: sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com
```

Comment: You're missing a Zookeeper port?

Comment: Well, I guess I tried that too, but I gave up on SAM. Instead I used Tranquility to push data to Druid more manualy. 
I used this: http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html
If someone is iterested

Comment: I saw this video a few months ago. Seems to do something like you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvtdvoZ83uk